# Tamanho máximo possível de alocar um vetor

Tags: c, array, c++

Gente, estou com um projeto de estrutura de dados que serve pra analisar algoritmos de busca no maior vetor possível que minha máquina consegue alocar. Alguém pode me auxiliar em descobrir como crio um vetor de tamanho máximo?

A linguagem é C++

Comment: Cara, a resposta está abaixo, mas só um alerta. Cuidado para não estourar a memória...

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [`std::vector::max_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size), essa função membro do `std::vector` retorna o número máximo de elementos que um `std::vector` consegue segurar em um sistema ou implementação específica.

Por exemplo ([veja online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9dc4d5ad7ec1977)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<char> v;
    std::cout << "Tamanho máximo: " << v.max_size() << '\n';
}
```

Para alocar essa quantidade de elementos contiguamente, utilize a função membro `reserve(size_type)` com o retorno de `max_size()`, ou (se quiser já construir os elementos no lugar) `resize(size_type)` igualmente. Por exemplo:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.resize(v.max_size()); // `v` agora contém `v.max_size()` elementos
                            // inicializados com zero.
}
```

Tome bastante cuidado com isso, aliás, pois esse tanto de memória é ridiculamente grande. Vários processos no sistema podem começar a falhar devido a falta de memória (consumida por esse vector).